# Choose the size of the figures in the colorbar of a colormap

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I have this code which is working (I took it from this forum). I would like to add a possiblity, which is to change the size of the figures, on the right of the colorbar. Can someone help me ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

X = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 200)
Y = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 200)
Z = X*np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)

contour = plt.tricontourf(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap="bwr")

def fmt(x, pos):
    a, b = '{:.2e}'.format(x).split('e')
    b = int(b)
    return r'${} \times 10^{{{}}}$'.format(a, b)

cbar = plt.colorbar(contour, format=ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))
cbar.set_label('Colorbar label', size = 15)

plt.show()
```

I had this image to help:

[image]

Thanks a lot !